# Yesod sample projects

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am planning to write a yesod  web application. And I'm wondering whether there are some large project using yesod  that is well designed that I could look at and experiment with.
I am looking for open source projects. I can learn from.

Comment: haskellers was written in yesod

Comment: same with http://www.fpcomplete.com

Comment: Thanks guys, Does any of those projects have their source code available?

Comment: Source for haskellers (https://github.com/snoyberg/haskellers), pbrisbin's page (http://pbrisbin.com/) is also worth looking at (https://github.com/pbrisbin/devsite).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been developing a web application that focuses on media sharing mainly inside home network, and acted as a excercise for me. 
This was the first project for me using Yesod, and in fact the first larger project written in Haskell, but maybe there is something to learn from it.

There's stuff like reused widgets, custom sql queries (could probably use esquelato nowadays), hashdb authentication/access control and plugin-like *sections*-thingy for handling different types of files in share.

**Disclaimer:** This is my personal project developed purely for my needs, and I have not had the time to upgrade the code base for Yesod 1.2 nor do I consider it stable or well-designed.

The source code: https://github.com/SimSaladin/rnfssp

An in-production demo can be found at https://ssdesk.paivola.fi

Comment: The second link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

As an update for this answer there is now a [page of these on the Yesod wiki](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Powered-by-Yesod), including [the source](https://github.com/garry-cairns/ILikeWhenItWorks) for [my own site](https://ilikewhenit.works/).